Power supply for WS2812B
I want to build an Ambilight-like system with WS2812B and some controller.
These are the devices I think about:
WS2812B LED Strip 5 m 60 LEDs/m
https://amzn.eu/d/9Nrg8kc (SP108E WIFI Controller)
What power supply I should by for them if I want to use the standard power socket? If my maths is correct, I should use 5V 18A

18A feels like a lot, and on the picture I see 24V, not 5V, so no, your math is not correct. Also, don't those things come with a power supply?

It's 5-24 depending on the LED strip, for example this one is 5V https://pixel-imperium.de/5m-black-ws2812b-rgb-led-pixel-stripe-60leds-m-ip30-5v

but still then 18A is an awful lot, I have trouble finding anything much more than 6A

And that's why I'm asking!
